# Tikz axis y line=top tick does not appear

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-}, every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=top,
    axis y line=middle,
    xmin=0, xmax=1.0,
    ymin=0, ymax=1.0,
    xtick={0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0},
    ytick={0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The ytick 1.0 does not appear (or its label). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\pgfplotsset{axis y line*/center/.code={%
    \def\pgfplots@yaxislinesnum{1}%
    \def\pgfplots@ytickposnum{2}%
    \let\pgfplots@yticklabel@pos\pgfutil@empty
}}
```

The full code:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-}, every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}
\makeatletter   
\pgfplotsset{
    axis y line*/center/.code={\def\pgfplots@yaxislinesnum{1}\def\pgfplots@ytickposnum{2}\let\pgfplots@yticklabel@pos\pgfutil@empty},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=top,
    axis y line=middle,
    xmin=0, xmax=1.0,
    ymin=0, ymax=1.0,
    xtick={0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0},
    ytick={0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`axis y line=left` instead of `axis y line=middle`?

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz, which loads graphicx
\usepackage{bm}

\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-}, every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=top,
    axis y line=left,
    xmin=0, xmax=1.0,
    ymin=0, ymax=1.0,
    xtick={0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0},
    ytick={0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you comment out `axis y line=middle` it works. If you need `axis y line=middle`, try adding a tiny extra bit to the y range. Setting `ymax=1.0000001` will work.

Comment: Thanks, it does work, but it is a workaround. I will see if someone offers a genuine solution, and if not, I'll accept yours.